# Have biblatex-chicago refer to first mention in subsequent notes

Tags: biblatex-chicago

In the notes version of biblatex-chicago, the first citation gives a full citation in footnotes while any subsequent citations will only give the last name and short title. Is there any way to add the footnote number where the full citation is used?

So in the example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
    @book{book1,
        title = {First Book title},
        author = {Author, The},
        location = {Place},
        publisher = {Publisher},
        date = {2020},
    }
    @book{book2,
        title = {Second Book title},
        author = {Author, Another},
        location = {Place},
        publisher = {Publisher},
        date = {2020},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{biblio}
\begin{document}
Here is\footcite{book1} some\footcite{book2} text as filler.\footcite{book1}

\end{document}
```

The output of note 3 should be "Author, First book title (ref. 1)" instead of just "Author, First book title"

To get this to work properly, I would also require citations to be reset at the start of each chapter.

Comment: I found out I could reset the citations per chapter by adding to option citereset=chapter when calling biblatex-chicago in case anyone else was wondering.

\usepackage[notes,citereset=chapter]{biblatex-chicago}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard style `verbose-note` offers an option like this, so we can try and transplant its code into `biblatex-chicago`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

% Taken from verbose-note.cbx
\newtoggle{cbx:pageref}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{pageref}[true]{%
  \settoggle{cbx:pageref}{#1}%
  \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{pagetracker}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{seenote}{%
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
         {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
          \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}}%
}

% Simplified version of chicago-notes.cbx's definition
% cf. also the definition in verbose-note.cbx
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:save}{%
  \iffootnote
    {\csxdef{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}{\the\value{instcount}}%
     \label{cbx@\the\value{instcount}}}%
    {}}%

\makeatletter
% Just add a call to \usebibmacro{seenote} to the definition
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}[1]{%
  \global\let\cms@pnsaved\undefined%
  \ifcsundef{cite:short:#1}%
    {\csuse{cite:short:book}}%
    {\csuse{cite:short:#1}}%
   \setunit{\addspace}%
   \usebibmacro{seenote}}%
\makeatother


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
  title     = {First Book title},
  author    = {Author, The},
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date      = {2020},
}
@book{book2,
  title     = {Second Book title},
  author    = {Author, Another},
  location  = {Place},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date      = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is\footcite{book1} some\footcite{book2} text as filler.\footcite{book1}
\end{document}
```

[image: Author, First Book title (see note 1).]

*edit* Updated for version 2020/04/20 of `biblatex-chicago`. See the edit history for code working with older versions.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. I just replaced the "\bibstring{seenote}" for "Ref." as that was the string I needed. Is there anywhere I can change the seenote bibstring so that it works more rigorously?

Comment: @ChaokangTai You can change the bibstring with `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{seenote = {ref\adddot}}`.

Comment: This used to work fine but now I suddenly get the error `Bibliography macro 'cite:short:cms' undefined.` What causes that?

Comment: @cktai The recent update to `biblatex-chicago` has completely changed the definition of `cite:short`. Check out the edit, please.

Comment: awesome that fixed it, thanks!